# Commandline http download tool for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, http

Is there a built-in command line tool for downloading files from the internet? I know there is wget for windows, which is fantastic piece of technology, but I am not allowed to install it :( I just need basic functionality - connect to a url and save contents to disk (or push to sdtout).

Comment: wget doesn't need installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If inputting a HTTP request by hand is no problem then you can use telnet to connect on port 80. But [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) seem easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firefox installed, then you can install the iMacros for Firefox addon even with only normal user rights. It is a browser automator. You can use it - among many other things - to [download files via the command line](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support).

Answer (score 0):

How about [URL2Disk](http://www.blocsoft.com/fwMore.asp?Title=url2disk) .I found it [here](http://www.shivaranjan.com/2008/09/13/download-files-from-internet-using-windows-command-line/)

They say it supports download of images, files, audio file, video file etc.

Answer (score 0):

Via FTP there's an `ftp` command available on Windows since XP.

Aside from the ones mentioned already, I've found [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) to be an excellent CLI downloading utility. It supports HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, Bittorrent and Metalink downloads.

Answer (score 0):

After windows 10 Insider build 17063 `curl` is default included with windows.